# Mockito, how to mock call by reference method on same class

Tags: spring, mockito

Why I can not mock callRefMethod method (call method by reference) on below code? The problem is real method of callRefMethod always being called.

```
public class ManageUserService {

    public void callRefMethod(List<String> lsStr, boolean flag){
        if (flag){
            lsStr.add("one");
            lsStr.add("two");
        }
 
    }

    public void methodA(){
        List<String> lsStr = new ArrayList<>();
        lsStr.add("zero");
        this.callRefMethod(lsStr, true);
        for(String str : lsStr){
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Unit tests:

```
public class ManageUserServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private ManageUserService manageUserService;
  
    private AutoCloseable closeable;

    @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        closeable = MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }

    @AfterEach
    void closeService() throws Exception {
        closeable.close();
    }

    @Test
    void methodATest(){
        List<String> lsData = new ArrayList<>();
        lsData.add("start");
        ManageUserService manageUserServiceA = new ManageUserService();
        ManageUserService userSpy = spy(manageUserServiceA);
        doNothing().when(userSpy).callRefMethod(lsData, true);
        userSpy.methodA();
        verify(userSpy).callRefMethod(ArgumentMatchers.any(ArrayList.class), ArgumentMatchers.any(Boolean.class));
    }
}
```

The result :

```
zero
one
two
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the difference between the list you're creating in the test method, which is used to match the expected parameters when "doing nothing":

```java
List<String> lsData = new ArrayList<>();
lsData.add("start");
...
doNothing().when(userSpy).callRefMethod(lsData, true);
```

and the list created in the tested method, passed to the spy object:

```java
List<String> lsStr = new ArrayList<>();
lsStr.add("zero");
this.callRefMethod(lsStr, true);
```

You're telling Mockito to `doNothing` if the list is: `["start"]`, but such list is never passed to the `callRefMethod`. `["zero"]` is passed there, which does not match the expected params, so actual method is called.

Mockito uses `equals` to compare the actual argument with an expected parameter value - [see: the documentation](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.3.3/org/mockito/Mockito.html#argument_matchers). To work around that `ArgumentMatchers` can be used.

You can either fix the value added to the list in the test or match the expected parameter in a less strict way (e.g. using `anyList()` matcher).

Comment: doNothing().when(manageUserServiceOne).callReffMethod(anyList(), anyBoolean()). this code still not working properly the result is only [zero]. the expected result should be [start]  (the mocking list).

Comment: Why is that the expected result? After moving to `anyList()` the `lsData` variable in the test is effectively unused - an element is added and later on the list is never mentioned in the code. You would have to pass it to the `methodA` to be used in any way.
What would you like your code to do/test?

Comment: ok thanks for the response, my expectation is modifying List parameter on  callReffMethod(List<String> lsStr, boolean flag);.  but finally i find the way by using  doAnswer((invocation) -> {
            System.out.println(invocation.getArgument(0).toString());
            List<String> lsAja = invocation.getArgument(0);
            lsAja.add("mockA");
            lsAja.add("mockB");
            return null;
        }).when(manageUserServiceOne).callReffMethod(anyList(), anyBoolean());

Answer (score 0):

ok i did it by using : where manageUserServiceOne is spy of ManageUserService class

```
 void methodATest(){
        List<String> lsData = new ArrayList<>();
        lsData.add("start");
        doAnswer((invocation) -> {
            System.out.println(invocation.getArgument(0).toString());
            List<String> lsModify = invocation.getArgument(0);
            lsModify.add("mockA");
            lsModify.add("mockB");
            return null;
        }).when(manageUserServiceOne).callRefMethod(anyList(), anyBoolean());
        manageUserServiceOne.methodA();
        verify(manageUserServiceOne).callRefMethod(ArgumentMatchers.any(ArrayList.class), ArgumentMatchers.any(Boolean.class));
    }
```